# Mapbox map wont reload on homepage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm having a really odd problem. I'm building a Rails application. I added a map from Mapbox. When I initially load the application the map works just fine, but if I go to another path and then come back to the homepage via a link inside the application (for example the app logo in the top left corner which redirects to the homepage) then the map won't load at all. If I get back via a "back" button on the browser then the map will load only the markers but not the actual map. If I refresh the page I can see the map again but the marks won't be focused in the center as they should. Only a hard reset will make the map work as it should again.

Google isn't helping me at all with this one. I hope someone here can guide me.

home.html.erb

```
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>All our Meals</h1>
    <div class="card-container-search">
      <div class="align-items-center">
        <%= form_tag root_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "What local meal are you looking to experience?", class:"form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "search-button"%>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around ">
  <div class="card-container">
    <% @meals.each do |meal| %>
      <div class="card" id="meals">
        <%= cl_image_tag meal.photos.first.key, class: 'card-image' if meal.photos.size>0 %>
        <div class="card-text">
         <h4><%= link_to meal.name, meal_path(meal), class: "adress-link" %></h4>
          <p><%= meal.address %></p>
          <p><%= meal.min_eaters %></i>-<i><%= meal.max_eaters %> eaters</p>
          <p>$</i> <%= meal.price %></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div
  id="map"
  style="height: 100vh; width: 100%"
  data-mapbox-api-key="<%= ENV['MAPBOX_API_KEY'] %>"
  data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>"
  ></div>
</div>
```

application.html.erb

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Homet</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-xl navbar-light bg-light d-flex justify-content-between">
      <%= link_to 'HomEt', root_path, class: "navbar-brand"%>

      <div class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-end flex-row-reverse align-items-center">
        <% if user_signed_in? then %>
            <%= link_to 'Manage My Meals', offered_meals_path, class: "nav-link"%>
            <%= link_to 'Manage My Bookings', bookings_path, class: "nav-link"%>
            <%= link_to "Log-out",
            destroy_user_session_path,
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to log out?" },
            class: "nav-link"%>
          <%else%>
            <%= link_to 'Sign-Up', new_user_registration_path, class: "nav-link"%>
            <%= link_to 'Log-in', new_user_session_path, class: "nav-link"%>
        <%end%>
      </div>

    </nav>
    <!-- flash messages for authentication -->
    <% if notice %>
      <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <%= notice %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% if alert %>
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <%= alert %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer-links">
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-copyright">
        © <%= Date.today.year %> Homet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

meals_controller.rb

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :home]
  before_action :set_meal, only: %i[edit update destroy show]

  def home
    if not params[:search].blank?
      @meals = policy_scope(Meal.where("name ilike?", "%#{params[:search]}%"))
      @query = params[:search]
    else
      @query = nil
      @meals = Meal.geocoded
    end
    @markers = @meals.map do |meal|
        {lat: meal.latitude,
         lng: meal.longitude,
         infoWindow: render_to_string(partial: "infowindow", locals: { meal: meal })
       }
     end
    @meals = policy_scope(@meals)
  end


  def show
    @meal = Meal.find(params[:id])
    authorize @meal
    @meal_owner = @meal.user
    user_bookings = @meal.bookings.where(user: current_user)
    if user_bookings.empty? or user_bookings.last.date < Date.today
      @booking = Booking.new
    else
      @booking = @meal.bookings.where(user: current_user).last
    end

    @open_days = ""
    @days = @meal.open_days.length
    if @days == 1
      @open_days = "on #{@meal.open_days.first}s"
    elsif @days == 7
      @open_days = "everyday"
    elsif @meal.open_days.sort == ["Friday", "Monday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
      @open_days = "on weekdays"
    elsif @meal.open_days.sort == ["Saturday", "Sunday"]
      @open_days = "on weekends"
    elsif @meal.open_days.length > 1
      @last_day = @meal.open_days.last
      @first_days = @meal.open_days.take(@days - 1) * "s, "
      @open_days = "on #{@first_days}s and #{@last_day}s"
    end
  end

  def offered
    @meals = policy_scope(current_user.meals.all)
  end

  def new
    @meal = Meal.new()
    authorize @meal
  end

  def create
    @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)
    @meal.user = current_user
    authorize @meal
    if @meal.save
      redirect_to meal_path(@meal)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @meal = Meal.find(params[:id])
    authorize @meal
  end

  def update
    authorize @meal
    if @meal.update(meal_params)
      redirect_to meal_path(@meal)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @meal
    @meal.destroy
    redirect_to offered_meals_path
  end

  private

  def set_meal
    @meal = Meal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def meal_params
    params[:meal].parse_time_select! :open_hrs
    params[:meal].parse_time_select! :close_hrs
    params.require(:meal).permit(:name,
                                 :description,
                                 :price,
                                 :address,
                                 :min_eaters,
                                 :max_eaters,
                                 :open_hrs,
                                 :close_hrs,
                                 open_days: [],
                                  photos: []
                                 )
  end
end
```

application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("custom/carousel")



// External import
import "bootstrap";
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css';
import { initAutocomplete } from '../plugins/init_autocomplete';

import { initMapbox } from '../plugins/init_mapbox';

initMapbox();
initAutocomplete();

// Internal imports, e.g:
// import { initSelect2 } from '../components/init_select2';

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  // Call your functions here, e.g:
  // initSelect2();
});
```

init_mapbox.js

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder'

const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

const addMarkers = (map, markers) => {
  markers.forEach((marker) => {
  const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML(marker.infoWindow);
  new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([ marker.lng, marker.lat ])
    .setPopup(popup)
    .addTo(map);
  });
};


const fitMapToMarkers = (map, markers) => {
  const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
  markers.forEach(marker => bounds.extend([ marker.lng, marker.lat ]));
  map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 60, maxZoom: 11, duration: 0 });
};
const initMapbox = () => {
  if (mapElement) {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = mapElement.dataset.mapboxApiKey;
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/***'
});

const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);

  fitMapToMarkers(map, markers);
  addMarkers(map, markers)
  map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken }))

  }
};

export { initMapbox };
```

init_autocomplete.js

```
import places from 'places.js';

const initAutocomplete = () => {
  const addressInput = document.getElementById('meal_address');
  if (addressInput) {
    places({ container: addressInput });
  }
};

export { initAutocomplete };
```

Please feel free to paint anything you see wrong with my code!

Comment: When the map isn't displaying, are you seeing any errors in the console or requests to Mapbox endpoints returning status codes other than `200: OK` in the network requests?

Comment: On the console: `index.js:243 No mapboxgl detected in options. Map markers are disabled. Please set options.mapboxgl`. But I get that every time, when the map works and it doesn't work. On the network everything is 200 except something related to the access token, which returns 204, I get this same status code when the maps works as intended